# Android to BLE write fails when writing more than a few bytes in quick succession

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can successfully write to an RN4020 module from my Android device. An LED lights up on the module to indicate successful receipt of transmission and I can see the ASCII character transmitted to RN4020 on an Arduino terminal.

The problem is: when I try to send characters in quick succession (for example, each time when a button on my Android app is pressed very quickly) then after 5 to 10 successful transmissions:

1. RN4020 stops receiving: the LED to indicate Rx never turns on and I can't see transmitted characters on the terminal.
2. Most times Android device doesn't recognize that the write failed but sometimes I get the following error:

   D/BluetoothGatt: writeCharacteristic: mDeviceBusy = true, and return false

My code to write to BLE (everytime a button is clicked I call sendDataToRN4020):

```
public boolean sendDataToRN4020(char instruction){

    //check mBluetoothGatt is available
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "lost connection");
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("<address uuid>"));
    if (Service == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "service not found!");
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("<service uuid>"));
    if (charac == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");
        return false;
    }

    byte[] value = new byte[1];
    value[0] = (byte) (instruction);
    charac.setValue(value);
    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac);
    return status;
}
```

This is my callback for writeCharacteristic:

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Successful transmission"); 
        }

}
```

Comment: You can't perform another write until the previous one has finished.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are already answers to this problem if you search... basically you need to queue your requests using a `Queue` (`LinkedList`). Each time you want to write a characteristic you add it to the queue, then in your callback, call your method to process the next request. The GATT implementation is synchronous.

Comment: @DigitalNinja can you please give an example of what the code will look like, specifically, in the callback, how can I keep track of which request to process next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was eventually resolved. The code in the question runs perfectly on a recently released Android device. The reason the failure was happening was that the device being used for testing at the time of posting this question was at least 3 years old. Newer devices have more robust support for BLE.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an Answer to your problem but I have not enough reputation to comment so I made an answer, I worked in an application using BLE to transfer data, I ran into a problem similar in which the app stops transmission even when the BLE device it's displaying that there's connection, this was because I had a scanner for compatible BLE devices, sometimes the app connects to a device multiple times because the app is constantly scanning for signals, don't know if you are doing something similar but I would recommend the following, before making a connection make sure that if there's a previous one, disconnect:

```
public static void connect(final String address, final String devicename, Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && address != null) {
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device != null) {
            forceDisconnect();
            Log.i(TAG,"starting connection");
            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, mGattCallback);
        }
    }
```

This is the method to disconnect:

```
    public static void forceDisconnect(){
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();    //  from any connected device
        if (mBluetoothGatt != null) mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is going to be of any help, what I can tell you is that after I did this adjustments to my code I was able to send data from the BLE device without issues, perhaps it's worth knowing how is your connection code to the BLE device, anyways hope it helps.

Comment: In your case it seems to be easiest to simply don't connect another time if you are already connected to the same device? Anyway the correct answer to the question is that one must wait for onCharacteristicWrite before another request can be issued.

Comment: That was what I though initially but I had validations to not connect if there's a device already connected, I didn't engineer the hardware I was working with, but my guess was that the device didn't kept the transmission alive some how, it was a pretty early build from the hardware but this solved my problem, anyway I appreciate the feed back

Comment: @Emil can you please give an example of code that'll allow me to wait for onCharacteristicWrite before another request can be issued

Comment: @FabianAlmarazRuvalcaba I am absolutely certain that the Android remains connected to the BLE device. Connection is definitely not a problem. Thanks though. Any other suggestions will also be appreciated.

Comment: You could have a queue that you push your requests to. If there is no pending request - execute immediately. Otherwise in the callback (onCharacteristicWrite), check if there are any pending requests in the queue and if so execute it. This must be done in a thread safe way.